# Websocket to extend a azure service bus

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, websocket, azureservicebus

I'm writing a highly available api via rest and web sockets in .net. I'm looking for strategies for:

1. Keeping track of each of the open web sockets to my api app
2. How to consume either queue messages, or topics from an azure service bus in an asp.net webapi app
3. what patterns or strategies I should research

At this point, my key word searches are not providing me with a lot of insight on how to implement this, but if any one has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate suggestions!

**TL;DR:** anyone created a queue service in a webapi project to push messages down a websocket?

Comment: I found a tutorial about [Building Real-time Web Apps with ASP.NET WebAPI and WebSockets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets/), you could find `WebSocket` instance via access `WebSocketHandler.AspNetWebSocketContext.WebSocket` within `WebSocketCollection`. I could not better understand your scenario about using Websocket to extend a azure service bus, you could provide more details about your scenario.

Comment: awesome, thanks Bruce! reading the article now!

Comment: Hey Bruce, this is a great resource for implementing websockets in an api project, but my intent is to connect the socket, then wait for a message coming in from the azure service bus queue to then push down to the client when it comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My request was a bit convoluted. I was able to solve the problem via a Topic and subscription model.

I publish to the topic from the queue, and that broadcasts to all websocket connections via a filtered subscription that is generated on websocket request. pretty slick!

```
 private async Task ProcessWebsocketSession(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
    {
        var details = ((APIIdentity)User.Identity).Details;
        //SubscriptionHandler creates the subscription for the given system, and disposes of it safely when leaving scope
        using (var ws = context.WebSocket)
        using (var subHander = new SubscriptionHandler(details))
        {
            var client = subHander.Client;
            client.OnMessage((brokerMsg) => 
            {
                var payload = brokerMsg.GetBody<string>();
                var dataToSend = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(brokerMsg.GetBody<string>());
                //refreshing from db, to check if data has been updated in process
                dataToSend = Repo.GetData(BusinessID, dataToSend .ID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (dataToSend != null && !dataToSend Send.IsConfirmed.Value)
                {
                    byte[] binaryData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);
                    var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(binaryData);
                    var task = ws.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                        true, CancellationToken.None);
                    task.Wait();
                }
                brokerMsg.Complete();
            });
            var receivedBytes = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                // ping/pong response to verify socket is connected without changing data
                var msg = await ws.ReceiveAsync(receivedBytes, CancellationToken.None);
                if (msg.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Text)
                {
                    var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes.ToArray());
                    if (text.ToLower() == "ping")
                    {
                        await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text.ToCharArray())), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
                    }
                }

            } 

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> anyone created a queue service in a webapi project to push messages down a websocket?

Based on your requirement, you could create a background task for receiving the messages from your service bus queue as follows:

**Global.asax.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static ManualResetEvent _maunalResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            var connectionString = "";
            var queueName = "samplequeue";
            var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);
            client.OnMessage(message =>
            {
                var messageBody = message.GetBody<String>();
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(String.Format("Message body: {0}", messageBody));

               //TODO: send message to the specific client (user)
            });
            _maunalResetEvent.WaitOne();
        });
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        _maunalResetEvent.Set();
    }
}
```

**Note:** For more details about receiving message from queue, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues).

For pushing message to your client, if you based on the [webapi-and-websockets](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youssefm/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets/), I assumed that you need to pick up the `WebSocketCollection` instance, then choose the specific `WebSocketHandler` instance with the `_username` matches the property from the received queue message or broadcast the message to all clients as follows:

When receiving a queue message, then broadcast to all clients by using the following code:

```
ChatWebSocketHandler.ChatClients.Broadcast("{queue-message}");
```

[image]

Additionally, you could leverage [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) and map your client (user) to signalR connections, then when you receiving the queue message, you could send it to your client (user). For more details, you could refer to [Mapping SignalR Users to Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections). Also, you could follow [SignalR Hubs API Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server) and this [git sample](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/release/samples/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Samples).

Comment: the implementation I am writing is utilizing websockets as an integration point. requiring a signalR client is not my intent, but a basic string <--> string socket connection for push notifications to highly restricted (behind firewalls) networks that do not allow anything other than web traffic.